# Get group name from SID

Tags: go, winapi

I want to use `LookupGroupId` function in `os/user` with this definition :

```
func LookupGroupId(gid string) (*Group, error) {
    return lookupGroupId(gid)
}
```

and here is the `lookupGroupId` definition:

```
func lookupGroupId(gid string) (*Group, error) {
    sid, err := syscall.StringToSid(gid)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    groupname, _, t, err := sid.LookupAccount("")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    if t != syscall.SidTypeGroup && t != syscall.SidTypeWellKnownGroup && t != syscall.SidTypeAlias {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("lookupGroupId: should be group account type, not %d", t)
    }
    return &Group{Name: groupname, Gid: gid}, nil
}
```

and I want to run the lookup and then save the Name and SID in a variable which will be a var of type `Group` as below:

```
var userGroup = user.Group{Gid: "", Name: ""}
```

Already tried this, but nothing happens. Its like the app wont even save it anywhere.

```
user.LookupGroupId("S-1-5-32-545") // Users group SID
```

Which part I am doing wrong? I already tried this code as well:

```
userGroup, _ = user.LookupGroupId("S-1-5-32-545")
```

But I get this error:
`cannot assign *user.Group to userGroup (type user.Group) in multiple assignment`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error points out that you are returing two variables but only one variable is being used to capture it.

You could try like this and see if that works

```
userGroup, _ := user.LookupGroupId("S-1-5-32-545")
```

Comment: Now I'm getting this, I fixed the 2 variable error btw. `cannot assign *user.Group to userGroup (type user.Group) in multiple assignment`

Comment: you no need to have var userGroup = user.Group{Gid: "", Name: ""}, instead try this like  a, b := user.LookupGroupId("S-1-5-32-545") and try print a.Gid and a.Name

Comment: I already tired it with `userGroup, err := user.LookupGroupId("S-1-5-32-545")` but got this error `panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference`. After using your code, I no longer get this error. Can you explain why if you know?

Comment: I guess you must have declared userGroup as a pointer and not initialized it, though the question on the code seems ok to me.